# Can we Integrate JBPM Console and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

I am creating a workflow in Eclipse (provided by JBPM 7.1.0). I want everything that I am creating in Eclipse to get reflected on JBPM Web Console. Is is possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kie-workbench uses git repository to store assets, create repository in kie-workbench, clone it into IDE, create/update rules/processes and push the changes back to kie-workbench using standard git commands.